# Change Windows 7 Taskbar color programmatically

Tags: ruby, winapi, windows-7, aero, aero-glass

I want to make a background process, that changes Taskbar color on some occasions.
For example, it is currently black (0,0,0):

[image]

UPD: the language I am going to use is Ruby, so I thought that knowing the correct WinAPI function name would be enough to success.

Comment: This is not possible. Windows Themes allow the user to decide on the colors used system-wide, and applications can't override them. (And trying to do so isn't appropriate; the UI belongs to the user, and they should decide what colors are used.)

Comment: @KenWhite, no problem if solution would be system-wide.

Comment: As I just said, *that's not possible*. It's the *user's choice*, not the programmers, what colors are used.

Comment: Well it's possible, just not through public api. It is the user's choice.

Comment: @KenWhite I certainly agree with you that the UI belongs to the user, and they should decide what colors are used. Which is why, when IT pushes a `Do not allow color changes` group policy, we re-introduce the UI in a third party tool. Because the UI belongs to the user, and they should decide what colors are used. [*Setting a policy to remove the user interface for a feature is like removing the staircase that leads to the second floor to keep people out. If you let them bring a ladder, then they can still get up there*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080131-00/?p=23633)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is *undocumented* function `DwmSetColorizationParameters`, that was successfully used

in **C++**: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610909/Changing-Windows-Aero-Color
in **AutoIt**: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/141495-change-windows-7-aero-color/
in **VB**: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/99240c0d-0b05-49ae-81da-62f2992aecf0

But my naive **Ruby** approach to call this function by name gives `LoadError: unknown symbol "DwmSetColorizationParameters"`. I wonder if it is possible to get this function by address.

Comment: Don't start with Ruby. Check it out from C++ and if that works, port to Ruby.